# Measure BJT base voltage cause IC to increase, why?

Tags: transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmX7Fw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I measure the base voltage, the collect current will increase, why? The only equation that I come up with is $$V_B=5\times \frac{R_{meter}}{R_B+R_{meter}} $$ 
which tells me that if Rmeter decreases (open circuit to 10's of megaohms) VB will also be decrease. So I was expecting a drop in collector current rather than increase. Can anyone explain this to me, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the meter is in voltage mode? If it is in resistance measuring mode it will emit a small current in order to determine what the resistance is. Some of that current might travel through the base and give rise to increased collector current.

Comment: BJT is a current controlled semiconductor. Not based on voltage. Also, the collector current is proportional to the base current. Ic = current gain x Ib . So, as mkeith told when you try to measure a voltage, multimeter deliver a small current which might be going into the base region by which the collector current get increased while you measure!

Comment: Yes, is in voltage range. And I did Thévenin equivalent on the base side with different value of Rmeter, it turns out that when Rmeter drops, the base current will increase. Just thinking is there another way to understand this without going into Thévenin equivalent.

Comment: @Sam Since the emitter is at \$-5\:\text{V}\$, the base is going to be nearer to \$-4.3\:\text{V}\$. Your meter apparently is connected at one side to ground, which is (+) relative to those two voltages. So current will flow from ground, through the meter, and into the base and increase the net base current. This *should* increase the collector current, just as you observed. Nothing new here. Your equation is simply wrong, that's all.

Comment: Assuming vcc=5, vee=-5, beta is your BJT \$\beta\$, vt is 26 mV, isat is your BJT saturation current, and rm is your meter resistance, then your equation for the base voltage should be more like: (-beta \* vt \* (rb + rm) \* LambertW(isat \* rb \* rm \* exp((-beta \* vee \* (rb + rm) + rm \* (beta \* vcc + isat \* rb))/(beta \* vt \* (rb + rm)))/(beta \* vt \* (rb + rm))) + rm \* (beta \* vcc + isat \* rb))/(beta \* (rb + rm)). That *does* take into account the base of the BJT, now. And yes, it is very ugly. Easier to just say: "base is -4.3 V" and be done with it.

Comment: Dhans - where did you learn such wrong statements (...not based on voltage...) ?

Comment: LvW, I ain't say like that and to distinguish BJT as current controlled used that word...

Answer (score 3):

You say you're measuring the base voltage ... with no further qualification, that means the base voltage with respect to ground.

As the emitter is at -5V, that means base is around -4.3V, so an additional resistance to ground (your meter) will increase the base current.

Which increases the collector current as you observe.